# How to use backtrace() with addr2line to get line numbers of the call stack?

Tags: c++, debugging, backtrace, debug-backtrace

I'm trying to use `backtrace()` in conjunction with `addr2line` to obtain line numbers for a call stack.

Here's the content of my `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_stack_trace() {
  void *array[10];
  size_t size;
  char **strings;
  size_t i;

  // Get the current call stack
  size = backtrace(array, 20);

  // Convert it into an array of strings
  strings = backtrace_symbols(array, size);

  if (strings == NULL) {
    perror("backtrace_symbols");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Print all the stack trace symbols
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
  }

  free(strings);
}

void dummy_function() {
  // Generate a stack trace
  print_stack_trace();
}

int main(void) {
  // Call a function and then print the stack trace within that function
  dummy_function();
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code with the following command:

```
g++ -rdynamic -g3 main.cpp -o main.out
```

When I run the executable:

```
./main.out
```

The output is:

```
./main.out(_Z17print_stack_tracev+0x2c) [0x556c59bed235]
./main.out(_Z14dummy_functionv+0xd) [0x556c59bed2da]
./main.out(main+0xd) [0x556c59bed2ea]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7f9128c7bd90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7f9128c7be40]
./main.out(_start+0x25) [0x556c59bed145]
```

According to the `backtrace_symbols()` man page, the addresses in the brackets (e.g., `0x556c59bed2da`) are return addresses. I've compiled with the `-g` option and used `addr2line` as follows:

```
addr2line -f -e ./main.out 0x556c59bed2da
```

But the output is:

```
??
??:0
```

I checked the function addresses with `objdump`:

```
objdump -S -l -d ./main.out
```

The addresses seem to start with `0000`, like so:

```
0000000000001209 <_Z17print_stack_tracev>:
00000000000012cd <_Z14dummy_functionv>:
```

These do not match the `backtrace_symbols()` output (`0x556c59bed2da`).

How can I use `addr2line` to determine the line numbers of the call stack correctly?

Comment: _Side note:_ After all the other processing, you could pass the output through `c++filt` to get pretty print C++ names.

Comment: ASLR means that the addresses used at runtime (appearing in the backtrace) don't match the addresses in the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Find the base address of your process in memory by examining the `/proc/<PID>/maps` while your program is running. This is a line that has the name of your program and the permissions `r-xp` (executable segment).

Let's say the base address is `0x556c59bec000`. Then the address inside `_Z14dummy_functionv` in the .text map table is `0x556c59bed2da` minus `0x556c59bec000` is `12da`. Pass it to `addr2line`.